# AES Interoperability between PHP, Java, Javascript

Tags: java, php, javascript, encryption, aes

I'm developing a HTTP API that requires encryption. I have tried to use AES to get compatibility between Java, PHP and Javascript, but so far I have managed to get Java<->PHP and then Java<->Javascript, but not both PHP and Javascript at the same time.

Has anyone had any experience with achieving interoperability between these languages and more?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using HTTPS?  If not, why not?  If yes, why do you need an extra encryption layer?  (There can be legitimate reasons for it, I'm just curious if any of them really apply.)

Comment: The API is user based so there is already a shared secret (The user's password) so the overhead of SSL/TSL is theoretically unnecessary.

Comment: OK then, I just find it hard to believe that the overhead of SSL/TLS would be greater than that of doing AES in JavaScript.  (Also, I hope you're never sending that password in cleartext, then.)

Comment: Just a general note: [JavaScript cryptography is not a good idea.](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/)

Comment: Your question is too broad in its current form. What are you using for encryption/decryption in JavaScript/PHP? Show code.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen that article before and I'm taking that into account; I'll be at least using SSL to load the page to ensure javascript integrity and the final version may indeed pass through a proxy via SSL (it will still be forced to provide encrypted data to conform to the API though). Speed isn't vital via the Javascript interfaces. The use of encryption is to ensure that server-side requests are both secure and don't have the overhead of HTTPS.

Comment: Current PHP: http://codepad.org/gTf42tFo Java: http://codepad.org/PmbqU5nI

Answer (score 3):

To get AES to work across different systems, you have to make sure that **everything** is the same on all systems.  That means not relying on system defaults for anything - defaults can differ between systems.  You need to explicitly specify everything.

- specify the mode; use CBC or CTR.
- specify the IV.  You can prepend it to the cyphertext.
- specify the padding; for AES use PKCS7.
- if your key is a text string then specify the character encoding used to convert it to bytes.
- if your plaintext is a text string then specify the character encoding used to convert it to bytes.

Comment: My current java and php code has been linked in a comment in another answer. Can you see any reason why the two would not produce the same result?

Comment: My PHP is non-existent.  You obviously have work to do on the IV (symptom: first block of deciphered plaintext is garbage).  You need to specify the character encoding you are using at both ends (?UTF-8).  The same with the key.  There are a lot of potential problems with converting a string to bytes.  Explicitly specify *everyyhing*.  Otherwise I can't see any obvious errors.

Comment: @David Hoffmann: You need to get the IV to the application at the other end so it can decrypt correctly.  The usual way to send it is to prepend it to the cyphertext.  At the destination you separate the first sixteen bytes (16 bytes = 1 block) as the IV and the rest is the cyphertext.  The IV does not need to be kept secret, just the key.

Answer (score 1):

AES is a standard (defined [here](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf)). No matter which programming language you use, the result **has to be** the same.

Check some test vectors either from the official definition or - if you've already implemented a block mode of operation - from [here](http://www.inconteam.com/software-development/41-encryption/55-aes-test-vectors).

If your implementation has different result, it might work, but it won't be AES...

Comment: The main issue is that mcrypt (The standard PHP library that performs encryption) doesn't has AES, it has Rjindael; which as I understand is the algorithm that AES based on, but crucially is not identical. These differences are causing my problems I think. The AES Wikipedia page: AES has a fixed block size of 128 bits and a key size of 128, 192, or 256 bits, whereas Rijndael can be specified with block and key sizes in any multiple of 32 bits, with a minimum of 128 bits. The blocksize has a maximum of 256 bits, but the keysize has no theoretical maximum.

Comment: Couldn't you use [openssl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php) in PHP? It supports AES in all NIST-defined implementations.

Comment: Openssl looks promising. I've tried it out without success and I can't find much documentation. Even the php manual has limited information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php