# Java and c++ encrypted results not matching

Tags: java, c++, security, base64

I have a existing c++ code which will encrypt a string. Now I did the same encryption in .
   **Some of the encrypted strings are matching  . Some are mismatching in one or two characters.**

I am  unable to figure out why it is happening. I ran both the codes in debug mode  until they call their libraries both have the same key, salt, iv  string to be encrypted.

I know that even if a single byte padding change will modify encrypted string drastically. But here I am just seeing a one or two characters change. Here is a sample (Bold characters in between stars is the part mis matching)

**java:**

> U2FsdGVkX18xMjM0NTY3OGEL9nxFlHrWvodMqar82NT53krNkqat0rrgeV5FAJFs1vBsZIJPZ08DJVrQ***Pw***yV15HEoyECBeAZ6MTeN+ZYHRitKanY5jiRU2J0KP0Fzola

**C++:**

> U2FsdGVkX18xMjM0NTY3OGEL9nxFlHrWvodMqar82NT53krNkqat0rrgeV5FAJFs1vBsZIJPZ08DJVrQ***jQ***yV15HEoyECBeAZ6MTeN+ZYHRitKanY5jiRU2J0KP0Fzola

I am using AES encryption.  provider is SunJCE version 1.6. I tried changing provider to Bouncy Castle. Even then result is same.

Added One More sample:

**C++:**

> U2FsdGVkX18xMjM0NTY3O***I***/BMu11HkHgnkx+dLPDU1lbfRwb+aCRrwkk7e9dy++MK+/94dKLPXaZDDlWlA3gdUNyh/Fxv***oF***STgl3QgpS0XU=

**java:**

> U2FsdGVkX18xMjM0NTY3O***D***/BMu11HkHgnkx+dLPDU1lbfRwb+aCRrwkk7e9dy++MK+/94dKLPXaZDDlWlA3gdUNyh/Fxv***j9***STgl3QgpS0XU=

**UPDATE:**

As per the comments I feel base 64 encryption is the culprit. I am using Latin-1 char set in both places. Anything else that I can check

Comment: What happens if you decrypt the c++ output with java and vice versa?

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue with a non-confidential input string that you can provide, then perhaps someone can tell you which output is right, which may lead to the answer.

Comment: @Philip I didnt decrypt c++ result with java . I decrypted java result with c++. It is getting exception in the library call. I am sure that some thing is missing in java. As C++ code is being used from long time.

Comment: @Pasacal Cuoq I am sure that C++ one is correct. Because We have the same in perl. When I try decvrypting the both only C++ one is passing.

Comment: There is an interesting post in SO on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687096/aes-interoperability-between-php-java-javascript

Comment: There may be some knowledge over at http://s.tk/crypto

Comment: Does the difference appear around the same area of the text all the time? The difference in characters 81 and 82 suggests that this might be due to a difference in Base-64 encoding of the binary string.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight No. It is not the same place. Actually in some other ecnrypted resutls there are two or three places where the one or two characters are mismatching.

Comment: so you get an exception when decrypting with java, that's great ! would you mind providing an example stack-trace?

Comment: @Philipp No, I am decrypting with c++. It is getting exception in c++.

Comment: I think it may be a good idea to try and spot the pattern in the differences then: convert Base-64 strings to sequences of bytes, and print all pairs where there are mismatches. In this case, there is a single-byte difference (141 in C++, 63 in Java). If you print multiple pairs like that, a pattern may emerge.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I wil give a shot.It will be awesome if I can crack this. How come some get encrypted properly and some slightly vary?

Comment: Well, first you should capture the output of the encryptions, BEFORE base-64 encoding, and see if they are the same or different.

Comment: Possibly a character encoding issue? Have you tried looking at a hex dump of the raw byte data you feed the encryption functions to make sure they're the same in C++ and java? Also, provide some minimal code snippets to help repro the problem?

Comment: @ravi My guess is that when certain problematic values are missing from the sequence of bytes, the output is the same; when these values are included, the output changes. This is only a guess, though.

Comment: If the problem were on the input side of the encryption, the result would be completely different from that point forward.  Clearly the problem is on the output side.  One needs to first assure that the binary output is the same on both platforms, then follow the process of converting binary to Base-64 all the way through and figure where it's going wrong.  Most likely somewhere the binary data is being (mis)interpreted as char data, prior to feeding into Base-64 encoding.

Comment: @ravi: It would be helpful if you post your Java and C++ code.  The first mismatching letter in your first example is "P" vs "j".  The first mismatching letter in your second example is "I" vs "D".  It's interesting to note that there are 5 characters from "j" to "p", and 5 characters from "d" to "i".  You might look at the rest of your mismatches and see if there's a similar pattern on the input values, or on the output values in the locations where errors occur.  Then check your code for what might cause such patterns.

Comment: @ravi: You might also do side-by-side debugging, assuming that your Java and C++ code are organized the same way.  If you step each program at the same time, you should be able to identify when a variable value becomes different between the two programs.

Comment: The output looks mostly like Base64, except `*` is not a valid Base64 symbol.  What is the output format of the API you are using? Are *s part of the output?

Comment: @n.m. stars are not part of base 64. I just want to highlight the portions mismatching . Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @ravi, did you ever check for differences before the base64 encoding? What are you using to do the base64 encoding?

Comment: @Hot Licks: not necessary the *entire* rest of the output if chaining isn't used (which is unlikely) - after de-melting my brain a bit, I do agree that it's probably post-encryption, as even ECB mode encryption should see much more diverging results (at least a block) if inputs differ.

Comment: "I am using Latin-1 char set in both places."  If you were doing it correctly the character set should not come into play at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I learned many things in this discussion. Special thanks to Hot Licks. here is gist of problem and solution: After getting encrypted byte array i am doing character conversion. That is causing problem. So Now I modified code to directly to use the byte array for base64 encoding and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sigh!!

The problem almost certainly is that after you encrypt the data and receive the encrypted data as a **byte** string, you are doing some sort of character conversion on the data before sending it through Base-64 conversion.

Note that if you encrypt the strings "ABC*_**D**_*EFG" and "ABC_***G***_EFG", the encrypted output will be completely different starting with the 4th character, and continuing to the end.  In other words, the Base-64 outputs would be something like (using made-up values):

U2FsdGVkX18xMj

and

U2FsdGXt91mJpz

The fact that, in the above examples, only two isolated Base-64 characters (one byte) are messed up in each case pretty much proves that the corruption occurs AFTER encryption.

The output of an encryption process is a **byte** sequence, not a character sequence.  The corruption observed is consistent with erroneously interpreting the bytes as characters and attempting to perform a code page conversion on them, prior to feeding them into the Base-64 converter.  The output from the encryptor should be fed directly into the Base-64 converter without any conversions.

You say you are using the "Latin-1 char set in both places", a clear sign that you are doing some conversion you should not be doing -- there should be no need to muck with char sets.

Comment: Very well Explained... Thanks a lot. After getting encrypted byte array i am doing character conversion. That is causing problem. So Now I modified code to directly to use the byte array for base64 encoding and it resolved.

Comment: @ravi -- BTW, for a relative novice you did fairly well to isolate the problem (to the degree you did) by running the same text through both algorithms and observing the differences.  It's common for people to flounder about for weeks trying to get encryption to work, since they often fail to take an organized approach to debugging.

Answer (score 2):

First a bit of code:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
```

...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1j = "U2FsdGVkX18xMjM0NTY3OGEL9nxFlHrWvodMqar82NT53krNkqat0rrgeV5FAJFs1vBsZIJPZ08DJVrQPwyV15HEoyECBeAZ6MTeN+ZYHRitKanY5jiRU2J0KP0Fzola";
    String s1c = "U2FsdGVkX18xMjM0NTY3OGEL9nxFlHrWvodMqar82NT53krNkqat0rrgeV5FAJFs1vBsZIJPZ08DJVrQjQyV15HEoyECBeAZ6MTeN+ZYHRitKanY5jiRU2J0KP0Fzola";
    byte[] bytesj = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(s1j);
    byte[] bytesc = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(s1c);
    int nmax = Math.max(bytesj.length, bytesc.length);
    int nmin = Math.min(bytesj.length, bytesc.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < nmax; ++i) {
        if (i >= nmin) {
            boolean isj = i < bytesj.length;
            byte b = isj? bytesj[i] : bytesc[i];
            System.out.printf("%s [%d] %x%n", (isj? "J" : "C++"), i, (int)b & 0xFF);
        } else {
            byte bj = bytesj[i];
            byte bc = bytesc[i];
            if (bj != bc) {
                System.out.printf("[%d] J %x != C++ %x%n", i, (int)bj & 0xFF, (int)bc & 0xFF);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This delivers

```
[60] J 3f != C++ 8d
```

Now 0x3f is the code of the question mark.

The error is, that 0x80 - 0xBF are in Latin-1, officially `ISO-8859-1`, control characters.
Windows Latin-1, officially `Windows-1252`, uses these codes for other characters.

Hence you should use "Windows-1252" or "Cp1252" (Code-Page) in Java.

---

***Blundly***

In the encryption the *original* bytes in the range 0x80 .. 0xBF were replaced with a question mark because of some translation to ISO-8859-1 instead of Windows-1252 to byte[].

Comment: He should not be using code pages *at all* in the encryption process, until after the data is converted to Base-64.  (I suspect, however, that he is treating the encrypted binary as character data somewhere along the way, leading to the problem.)

Comment: Somewhere text is translated to bytes. In java that would be `s.getBytes("Windows-1252")` or something else (stream input). Already in that stage _(before encryption)_ it is going wrong.

Comment: @HotLicks: after reconsidering: String in java uses Unicode, a char is UTF-16. In C++ **the perspective is different**; nobody cares about the encoding. Best practice in Java is explicitly giving the encoding when going from byte[] to String.

Comment: If the data were garbled before encryption, the entire rest of the encrypted string (at least up to a block boundary) would be garbled, vs just the one byte (2 Base-64 chars).

Comment: Right. Hence the conversion to a `?`.

Comment: HE SHOULD NOT BE GOING FROM BYTE TO STRING -- The Base-64 encoding will return a string, but there should be no other place in the entire encryption process where a byte-to-string transformation is being done.

Comment: Sorry, I was not saying that. But encryption = String -> bytes -> base64 and decryption base64 -> bytes -> String. And either the original string is messed up or getting the bytes.

Comment: Encryption is `data -> encrypted bytes ->base64` and decryption is `base64 -> encrypted bytes -> data`.  Whether or not the `data` is interpreted as a string depends on the nature of the data -- it could very well be binary data of some sort.

Comment: The problem is clearly somewhere between encryption and base64 encoding.

Comment: Yes but the question mentioned the data being text in Latin-1. Evidently the bytes are wrong; the base64 encryption seems correct, identical. The question is, where the wrong byte stems from. And that seems to be the distinction of ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252.

Comment: The problem stems most likely stems from using character conversion somewhere where one shouldn't.  NO CHARACTER CONVERSION SHOULD BE NEEDED ANYWHERE in this sequence.  And a garbled conversion of one character going in to the encryption would cause all the characters after that point to be garbled.  Since, in all case listed, only one character at a time is garbled, clearly the garbling occurs AFTER encryption.

Comment: @HotLicks: that is the C/C++ perspective (without wide chars); translated to Java it would mean not using String or char, only byte[]. Somewhere, at some time String is almost inevitable, and then a character encoding must be applied.

Comment: Java has the "advanced" concept of `byte[]` that works just fine for binary data.  Encrypted data MUST be treated as binary, not characters.

Comment: @HotLicks: **True**. But I bet the original Java code somewhere uses String. Let us stop this difference of opinion and let the others decide. P.S. no downvoting from me on your answer.